# margin auto between floated divs

Tags: html, css

I have a header in which i want to place three classes of elements.

First one is logo, which should be floated to the left.
Second one is a menu, which should be centered.
Third one is a button, which should be floated to right.

I am trying to achieve this structure as follows:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
</div>

.logo {
    float: left;
}
.menu {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.button {
    float: right;
}
```

However, when margin 0 auto is given to the menu, it takes all the space on the right side with margins and the button is pushed to the next line. How can I achieve what I want?

The situation is explained in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3LAz7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this you want to place your .menu div last.  So the new HTML will be

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @OzgurAkcali No problem! You can mark the answer as excepted if it worked

Comment: I will, but the system will let me do it in 10 minutes

Answer (score 2):

Change your menu div to last element.

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3LAz7/1/